# iis two certificate in same ip iis 8

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, iis-8

I have two certificate for two domain in same ip address in IIS 8

domain1.com

domain2.com

I import all certificate in iis (personal type) and add binding both domain in https The first domain has no problems in 443 and certificate working,but in domain2 when call over https the certificate of the first domain1 is called
I have the functionality SNI in domain2 but as before, the certificate of the first domain1 is displayed.

There is a solution to this issue?

Comment: https://www.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background Use Jexus Manager to troubleshoot, and whether you should properly configured SNI mapping would be easy.

Comment: Thanks you,jexusmanager there is no interference with iss and next to it?

Comment: It is just a self contained troubleshooting tool. In your case, you just need to use its HTTP API feature.

Comment: When i open Jexus Manager the iss express option is disabled and only jexus server is enabled,How can I enable them?

Comment: Run it as administrator and you should see the default IIS server node.

Comment: Thank you,resolved,and now display my node iis , but when try open connection get error :Could ot connect to the specified computer
Details: Filename:
C:\widows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config\applicationhost
line number: 149
Error: Value cannot be null
parameter name:source

Comment: @LexLi Do you know what is happening with this problem?(Line number: 1500 on section <ipSecurity> but when but when I delete all of them eventually error in the face Error: Value cannot be null parameter name:source without line number